# Ramda on arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js

```js
  var censusMembers = Object.freeze([
    {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob'
    }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Sue'
    }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Mary',
    household_id: 2
    }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Elizabeth',
    household_id: 6
    }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Tom'
    }, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Jill'
    }, {
    id: 7,
    name: 'John',
    household_id: 6
    }
    ]);
```

This is my array
I want to count the number of elements which has household id using ramda function ?
how can i do that ?

Comment: Why Ramda? this is possible using vanilla JS.

Comment: I am exploring ramda, can you please help using ramda ?

Comment: What Ramda techniques have you tried so far, then?

Comment: R.pipe(R.filter(R.propSatisfies(Boolean, ‘household_id’), R.length)

Comment: This should work fine.  I think you're simply missing a second parentheses before `, R.length`.  But see my answer for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`R.countBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#countBy) to count all items that have/don't have `household_id` using [`R.has()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#has), and than get the count for `true` using [`R.prop()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#prop):

```js
const { pipe, countBy, has, prop } = R;

const censusMembers = Object.freeze([{"id":1,"name":"Bob"},{"id":2,"name":"Sue"},{"id":3,"name":"Mary","household_id":2},{"id":4,"name":"Elizabeth","household_id":6},{"id":5,"name":"Tom"},{"id":6,"name":"Jill"},{"id":7,"name":"John","household_id":6}]);

const countHouseholders = pipe(
  countBy(has('household_id')),
  prop('true'),
);

const result = countHouseholders(censusMembers);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Don't use the function `filter` to count stuff because you're creating an array only to get the length.*

You can use the function [`R.reduce`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduce) and within the handler, check for the key `household_id`

```js
var censusMembers = Object.freeze([{id: 1,name: 'Bob'}, {id: 2,name: 'Sue'}, {id: 3,name: 'Mary',household_id: 2}, {id: 4,name: 'Elizabeth',household_id: 6}, {id: 5,name: 'Tom'}, {id: 6,name: 'Jill'}, {id: 7,name: 'John',household_id: 6}]);

// With household_id
//                                      (true is coerced to 1) = 1
console.log("With:", R.reduce((a, c) => ('household_id' in c) + a, 0, censusMembers));

// Without household_id
//                                         !(false is coerced to 0) = 1
console.log("Without:", R.reduce((a, c) => !('household_id' in c) + a, 0, censusMembers));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is little reason to introduce Ramda to a solution that works fine without it.  (`censusMembers.reduce(fn, 0)` versus `R.reduce(fn, 0, censusMembers)`.)  Ramda is all about building and composing functions.  I know that this is a learning exercise for the OP, but Ramda is not meant to be a Underscore/lodash replacement; it's meant to make it easier to write FP in JS.

Comment: @ScottSauyet for some reason that function is available in Ramda.

Comment: I am struggling on this how to Builb function that takes in an id and censusMembers and returns all dependents that belong to the user
 that has that id. 

If the id is of a dependent, or isn't in the censusMember array then the function should return null. If there are no dependents then the function should return an empty arrray.



example: if I give id as 6 then 

I should get this object
[{"id":4,"name":"Elizabeth","household_id":6},{"id":7,"name":"John","household_id":6}]

Comment: @Ele: The function is there so that you could write, for instance, `const sum = reduce(add, 0)`, creating a new function from an old one.  It adds little of use to say `const myTotal = reduce(add, 0, myNumbers)`.  There's nothing wrong with it, precisely.  I would write it that way if I was already using Ramda.  But it's not really what Ramda is designed for.

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava: Again, don't ask that in comments.  Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you are looking for something so different from the original question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996459/ramda-function-javascript-on-arrays. Please answer this I have updated

Answer (score 0):

[`has`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#has) looks to be what you're missing:

```js
var censusMembers = Object.freeze([
  {id: 1, name: 'Bob'}, 
  {id: 2, name: 'Sue' }, 
  {id: 3, name: 'Mary', household_id: 2 }, 
  {id: 4, name: 'Elizabeth', household_id: 6},
  {id: 5, name: 'Tom'}, 
  {id: 6, name: 'Jill'}, 
  {id: 7, name: 'John', household_id: 6}
]);

const countHouseholders = R.pipe(R.filter(R.has('household_id')), R.length)

console.log(countHouseholders(censusMembers))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: How to find number of elements which does not have household_id ?

Comment: You can replace `filter` by `reject` in the above, or wrap `has('household_id')` in `complement`.  Either should work.

Comment: I am struggling on this how to Builb function that takes in an id and censusMembers and returns all dependents that belong to the user
 that has that id. 

If the id is of a dependent, or isn't in the censusMember array then the function should return null. If there are no dependents then the function should return an empty arrray.



example: if I give id as 6 then 

I should get this object
[{"id":4,"name":"Elizabeth","household_id":6},{"id":7,"name":"John","household_id":6}]

Comment: Please ask another question for that.  Comments are meant for clarifications, etc.  Another question would be fine.

Comment: It says I have to wait 90 minutes so can you please reply here ?

Comment: Well, you're pretty clearly not a bot, which I think is what the throttling limit is meant for, so let me take a look.  Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava: And is `null` necessary?  It would be much simpler, and to my mind cleaner, to return an empty array.

Comment: This should return what you want, but with an empty list rather than `null`: `const getHouseholdById = (census, id) => filter(propEq('household_id', id), census)`.  Obviously, you could extend it by checking for an empty list and returning `null` if you get it.  But that sounds like a horrible API.  You can also wrap this in `curry` to allow you to partially apply `censusMembers`, and get a function on just `id`.