# ramda function javascript on arrays

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

```
const censusMembers = Object.freeze([
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Bob'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Sue'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Mary',
        household_id: 2
    }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Elizabeth',
        household_id: 6
    }, {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Tom'
    }, {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Jill'
    }, {
        id: 7,
        name: 'John',
        household_id: 6
    }
]);
```

In this array, A dependent can be determined by the presence of a household_id. The household_id is a reference to the ID of the employee that that member is a depended of (ex in the censusMembers list 'Mary' is a dependent of 'Sue')

How to build a function that takes in an id and the array of members(census members) and returns all dependents that belong to the user that has that id.

If the id is of a dependent, or isn't in the censusMember array then the function should return null.

If there are no dependents then the function should return an empty arrray.

for example:

if I give input as id 6
then output shoul be

```
[
{"id":4,"name":"Elizabeth","household_id":6}, 
{"id":7,"name":"John","household_id":6}
]
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: const countHouseholders = R.groupBy(R.propOr(0,'household_id'));

countHouseholders(censusMembers);

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, in this sample data, `7` or `8` would return `null` and `5` would return an empty array?  Is that correct?  If so, I personally find that a very uncomfortable API.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that seems to do what you would like:

```js
const {curry, find, propEq, has, filter} = R

const householdMembers = curry((census, id) => {
  const person = find(propEq('id', id), census);
  return person 
    ? has('household_id', person)
      ? null
      : filter(propEq('household_id', id), census)
    : null
})


var censusMembers = Object.freeze([
  {id: 1, name: 'Bob'}, 
  {id: 2, name: 'Sue' }, 
  {id: 3, name: 'Mary', household_id: 2 }, 
  {id: 4, name: 'Elizabeth', household_id: 6},
  {id: 5, name: 'Tom'}, 
  {id: 6, name: 'Jill'}, 
  {id: 7, name: 'John', household_id: 6}
])

const householders = householdMembers(censusMembers)

console.log(householders(6))
//=> [
//     {id: 4, name: 'Elizabeth','household_id': 6},
//     {id: 7, name: 'John', 'household_id': 6}
//   ]
console.log(householders(7))  //=> null
console.log(householders(8))  //=> null
console.log(householders(5))  //=> []
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

But I would suggest that you might want to rethink this API.  The empty array is a perfectly reasonable result when nothing is found.  Making it return `null` for some of these cases makes the output much harder to use.  For instance, if you wanted to retrieve the list of names of household members, you could simply write `const householderNames = pipe(householders, prop('name'))`.  Or you *could* do this if your function always returned a list.

Having a single function return multiple types like this is much harder to understand, and much, much harder to maintain.  Note how much simpler the following version is, one that always returns a (possibly empty) list:

```
const members = curry((census, id) => filter(propEq('household_id', id), census))
```